# Download a excel file stored in the storage in php

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I have an excel file present in the storage directory. I want that file to be downloaded once I click on "download excel" button.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using the "storage_path()", we get the storage path. And then by specifying the path and name we can download the file.
We need to pass the header for content-type as 'application/octet-stream'

```
       $file= storage_path(). "/excelFile.xlsx";
        $headers = array(
                  'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
                );
        return response()->download($file, 'excelFile.xlsx', $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Storage` Facade from Laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#downloading-files

When using the `disk('local')` it will look into the `storage/app` directory.

```php
 public function download()
    {
        return Storage::disk('local')->download('path-to-excel-file', 'filename.xlsx');
    }
```